# Framework for iOS Word Game

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uikit, game-engine

I'm developing an iOS Multiplayer word game and wondering whether I need to use cocos2d or a similar game engine? I do not need the physics engine but perhaps some animations and effects is all I would need from the engine. Will I be able to do these same effects from another library or with UIKit?

I do not want to use cocos2d unnecessarily(UIKit interfacing is faster) but if some things are just not possible without it. I'd rather be safe and use it. Any suggestions?

Comment: looking for information on capabilties rather than opinions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple released the new SpriteKit Framework, I recommend you to take a look at it. I would use it in your positon.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: It's similar to cocos2d, although simpler to implement, the questions is do I NEED it? Considering the low graphical complexity of word games.

Comment: You dont NEED it, you could do everything using UIKit, but it would make your life easier, trust me

Comment: You can also use a mix of both

Comment: will spritekit work on devices running ios6?

Comment: No, then you'll have to use Cocos2D or just go for UIKit